# Marshal struct with array member in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling

I'm using C# with P/Invoke to access to a DLL method. The definition of the method is the following:

```
[DllImport("userManager.dll")]
static extern int GetUsers(out IntPtr userList);
```

Original structs:

```
typedef struct user_list {
   unsigned short NumUsers;
   USER_LIST_ITEM List[VARLEN];
} USER_LIST

typedef struct user_list_item {
   char name[260];
   unsigned char address[256];
} USER_LIST_ITEM
```

And the struct layout I've done is the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class USER_LIST
{
    public uint NumUsers;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public USER_LIST_ITEM [] List;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class USER_LIST_ITEM
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string address;
};
```

But I get an error when I try to unmarshall it:

```
USER_LIST userList = new USER_LIST();
// Prepare pointer 
IntPtr uList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(userList));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(userList, uList, false);
result = GetUsers(out uList);

Marshal.PtrToStructure(uList, userList); <--
```

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x79f82af6, on thread 0x464. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

I get the NumUsers property right, but it seems the error occurs when unmarshalling the array. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the signature of the original GetUsers function?

Comment: Why do you allocate space/prepare a pointer? `out uList` means that `uList` will get overwritten but no value is passed to the native code.

Comment: The original signature is:
STATUS UMAPI GetUsers(
    OUT USER_LIST** userList
);

Comment: Okay. Next question: Who is responsible for allocating the memory? The caller (C# code) or the function (native code)?

Comment: What's a `OUT USER_LIST**`? A triple pointer!?

Comment: I guess the native code as in plain C works fine without allocating memory

Comment: Why the double (triple?) pointer then? Do you have an example how the function is supposed to be called (in C)?

Comment: OUT is nothing, just a decoration. It is a pointer to a list of USER_LIST. The function will simply write to the pointer provided.

Comment: This is how it works with plain C:
USER_LIST* user_list;
res = GetUsers(&user_list);

Comment: THe USER_LIST is the struct defined above

Comment: And how do you free user_list? Sounds painful.

Comment: `USER_LIST* user_list; res = GetUsers(&user_list);` -- this doesn't allocate memory for the user list items, no?

Comment: The Dll has a method to deallocate memory (UMFree(user_list))

Comment: After that call I get the USER_LIST filled with all the data, so I guess it does. I can then iterate through the inner list

Comment: I believe all memory is allocated by GetUsers, so no need to allocate memory in managed code. Just use UMFree to free the memory. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: So how do you know when the user list stop? You have some secret agreement that the last entry will be NULL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify an array in a structure used as an `out` parameter, you need to tell the marshaler what length is the array going to be. With your code, the marshaler is probably allocating a zero-length array or just using `null`, which produces the crash. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to specify a variable-length `out` array as a member of a structure, because `MarshalAs.SizeParamIndex` only works for methods. You might get away with specifying a large, constant-size array using `MarshalAs.SizeConst`, but generally you'd have to parse the (presumably callee-allocated) return buffer like this:

```
var count = Marshal.ReadInt32 (uList) ;
var users = new List<USER_LIST_ITEM>  () ;
var ptr   = (long)uList + 4 ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
{
    users.Add (Marshal.PtrToStructure (typeof (USER_LIST_ITEM), 
        new IntPtr (ptr))) ;
    ptr += Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (USER_LIST_ITEM)) ;
}
```

You'll have to pay extra attention to alignment&padding and 32/64 bit issues.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `List` has not been allocated yet.

You will need initialize all the fields.

Another problem I see is with the following:

```
IntPtr uList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(userList));
...
result = GetUsers(out uList);
```

Are you sure that `out` should not be `ref`? Else there is no point (not sure if `ref` is correct either).

Update: Looking at your code again, you should be doing this (and avoid that memory leak poking your eye).

```
IntPtr uList;
var result = GetUsers(out uList);

var userlist = (USER_LIST) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ulist, typeof(USER_LIST));

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ulist); // pray here or shoot the author of the C function
```

Update again:

Your p/invoke signature is likely wrong or you are interpreting it wrong.

I can guess it probably something like:

```
int GetUsers(USER_LIST* ulist);
```

And that what you have is not the same thing.

If this is case, the solution is easy.

Change `USER_LIST` to a class (but keep sequential layout) and use

```
// pinvoke sig
int GetUsers(USER_LIST ulist);

var ulist = new USER_LIST();
// initialize fields
var r = GetUsers(ulist);
```

-- or --

Call it by `ref`.

```
// pinvoke sig
int GetUsers(ref USER_LIST ulist);

var ulist = new USER_LIST();
// initialize fields
var r = GetUsers(ref ulist);
```

This way, you dont have to mess with manual marshalling, and I cant see anymore potential for memory leaks.

Final update:

Given the signature you posted, it looks like `GetUsers` returns a pointer to a list of `USER_LIST` with the return value being the count. Nice memory leak there.

Anyways, I would probably experiment with an unsafe approach here, and just walk thru the result , and make sure everything gets freed. (I still think you should shoot the author).

Comment: The return is either 0 or 1, just to show the success of the call

Comment: @Sergi: then you have a big leak and a nice buffer overrun to boot!

Comment: @Sergi: going unsafe will probably look just like the C, and might be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I think your original code isn't probably so wrong. 
You've probably just used the [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ex8z62.aspx) of [Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx).

Have you tried this?

```
[DllImport("userManager.dll")]
static extern int GetUsers(out IntPtr userList);

[DllImport("userManager.dll")]
static extern void UMFree(IntPtr userList);

static void Main()
{
    IntPtr userList;               // no need to allocate memory in managed code;
    GetUsers(out userList);        // memory is allocated by native function
    USER_LIST u = (USER_LIST)Marshal.PtrToStructure(userList, typeof(USER_LIST));
    UMFree(userList);
}
```

---

Using unsafe code:

```
public unsafe struct USER_LIST
{
    public uint numUsers;
    public USER_LIST_ITEM* list;
}

public unsafe struct USER_LIST_ITEM
{
    public fixed byte name[260];
    public fixed byte address[256];
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("userManager.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int GetUsers(USER_LIST** userList);

    [DllImport("userManager.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int UMFree(USER_LIST* userList);

    private static unsafe void Main()
    {
        USER_LIST* list;
        GetUsers(&list);
        UMFree(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but it's not working, I get the same error when PtrToStructure, I don't know if the structure definition is right, 'cause the code seem all right to me as well

Comment: I think the problem is the variable-sized array in the USER_LIST. How can the marshaller know it's size (it doesn't know that the size is stored in `NumUsers`). Using unsafe code is probably the best solution.

Comment: BTW, your structs in C# are actually declared as classes. Have you tried changing them to `struct`?